# How to loop through just those items in a slicer that are visible when the "Show items deleted from the data source" checkbox is unticked"?

Tags: excel, vba, slicers

I wish to use data from a slicer to build a list that then goes on a user form.  I only want those items that are visible (selected and unselected) when the "Show items deleted from the data source" checkbox is unticked on the 'Slicer Setting' form.  I had assumed it would have something to do with the VisibleSlicerItems property, but this returns the same value regardless of whether the box is ticked or not, despite there being a different number of items visible in the slicer.  Any help much appreciated.